# gravatar highest resolution

Tags: resolution, gravatar

I show a gravatr image of users in my site. How can I know the best highest resolution to use? e.g. which parameter "s" should be.

```
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=250
```

of course it depends in the user image, but gravatr must know the resolution of the initial image and can advise me on best highest size.

Comment: Wow, it's 2014 and still no definitive answer! =O

Comment: @Dang It is 2015, and no definitive answer yet :)

Comment: I contacted Automattic to ask for the `?s=native` option. I'll report back if they respond to my feature request.

Answer (score 16):

It seems the maximum size changed drastically in the last 9 month

> You may request images anywhere from 1px up to 2048px, however note that many users have lower  resolution images, so requesting larger sizes may result in pixelation/low-quality images.

quoted from the [Gravatar image Request tutorial](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it is possible, I just did some research on that matter because I have the same need, but I think Gravatar was designed for websites that will show all avatars at the same size, which means small avatars, and if it's too big for some of them, they'll be ok with the automatic upscaling.

They should include a "?s=native" to get the native size.

Answer (score 7):

This is what Gravatar writes about the resolution of the avatars:

> You may request images anywhere from 1px up to 2048px, however note
>   that many users have lower resolution images, so requesting larger
>   sizes may result in pixelation/low-quality images.

The highest resolution of the default image would be 2048px:)

Read more about Gravatar images (including the default image) on https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

**EDIT:** You will see the picture cannot get any bigger than 2048px x 2048px even if you set s=3000:)

**EDIT 2:** Apparently the maximum size changed from 512px to 2048px

Comment: thanks, this means in theory an image may be 512px, but in practice if I ask for this size I may see pixelation if the original image fits 200px. I'm looking for a way to find this out up front